# Excel VBA IfElse

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to this forum and VBA for Excel.

I want to compare the value of a cell (called "FOO", which has a simple excel formula in it = (C9/(C6+C7))*100, this outputs a % figure) to some other cell values (which I have called "Red" (value is an integer = 125), "Amber" (115), "Yellow" (105) and "Green" (95).  Basically, the code I want to write should write a string value into a cell called "indicator" - either Red, Amber, Yellow, Green.

I tried the code below, but I cant understand why the code isn't outputting to the Indicator Cell...its been a long exhausting week, and my brain is addled by my toddler - please help!

```
Option Explicit

Sub check()

Dim FOO As Long
Dim Red As Long
Dim Amber As Long
Dim Yellow As Long
Dim Green As Long
Dim Indicator As String

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")

 FOO = .Range("C8").Value
 Indicator = .Range("E4").Value
 Red = .Range("A1").Value
 Amber = .Range("A2").Value
 Yellow = .Range("A3").Value
 Green = .Range("A4").Value

End With

If FOO < Yellow Then
Indicator = "Green"

ElseIf FOO < Amber Then
Indicator = "Yellow"

ElseIf FOO < Red Then
Indicator = "Amber"

ElseIf FOO >= Red Then
Indicator = "Red"

End If

End Sub
```

PS, I had a go using Case If Select, but I cant make that work either ...I would be interested if there is a way of doing what I want using this function, as it seems more elegant.

Comment: If you want to store a percentage value use double instead of long

Comment: Thanks Santosh, I changed the FOO Declaration to Double, as I can see that is better practice for percentages that might not be integers.  But I still do not understand why the value of Range("E4") does not change from "blank" to the value I want ("Red/Amber/Yellow/Green"), based on running the code above...all advice gratefully received :)

Comment: Before exiting sub I can't see any where you are doing that just put `Sheets("test").Range("E4").Text = Indicator` before `End Sub`

Comment: And Indicator is not a cell its a variable of String data type

Comment: Santosh!  Thank you, I knew it was something obvious.  This works now, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is not required `Indicator = .Range("E4").Value`

This is required `Sheets("test").Range("E4").Text = Indicator` before `End Sub`